# How to catch time out exception when use RestTemplate call API

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I'm have function call api, use RestTemplate. I want catch exception when time out will return null, this is my code:

```
//Create resttemplate
public List<String> getRoleUser(String username) {
    try{
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(getClientHttpRequestFactory());
        String[] list = restTemplate.getForObject("(link call api)", String[].class);
        return Arrays.asList(list);
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

//Override timeouts in request factory
private SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory getClientHttpRequestFactory()
{
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory
                      = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    //Connect timeout
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(10_000);

    //Read timeout
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(10_000);
    return clientHttpRequestFactory;
}
```

but it don't work.
So, how can I return null when time out?

Comment: what do you mean `but it don't work.`? do you have any error message?

Comment: it don't work this mean not return null.

Comment: how can I catch exception if it time out, and return null in the function getRoleUser()?

Comment: I'm try and have message error, but not return null `org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "link call api": connect timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out `

Answer (score 0):

You should catch a HttpStatusCodeException exception:

```
try {
    restTemplate.exchange(...);
} catch (HttpStatusCodeException exception) {
    int statusCode = exception.getStatusCode().value();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue. After call API, I check value return of RestTemplate again. This code:

```
public List<String> getRoleUser(String username) {
        try {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(getClientHttpRequestFactory());
            String[] list = restTemplate.getForObject("link call api",
                    String[].class);
            if (list.length > 0) {
                return Arrays.asList(list);
            }
            return null;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Catching all exception is a bad design. Catch exception to return null is as much bad.